# Hot and cold 1/2 pex, straight run for outdoor shower, pvc 1.25 is that too narrow for both runs.?

Tags: outdoor, pvc, pex

Outdoor hot and cold faucets, idea was to attach 1/2 pex to  faucets and run through 1 1/2 pvc piping about 12" under ground for an Outdoor sbower, before pavers are installed.  Both pex lines fit in the 1 1/2 pvc, then arc upwards on each end until vertical. Due to supply chain issues, I could only find 1 1/2 pvc. Will it be too tight a fit to run both 1/2 pex together over the 30ft straight run? Or am I better separating hot and cold into 2 pvc runs or do I need a larger pvc pipe ( 2 inch or larger)?

Comment: You say it's a "straight run", then say "arc upwards". Will the PVC conduit be curved, or will the PEX "arc upwards" after leaving the PVC? I can't imagine that the 2 of them will be easy to pull through a PVC elbow, even a long-sweep elbow. Also, consider leaving the plumbing aisle and go look at PVC electrical conduit. You may find larger diameter Sch 40 down there. There's no difference between the two for _your_ intended purposes. (Note: You _must not_ run electrical in water PVC, but I don't see any reason you couldn't put PEX in electrical PVC.)

Comment: As a side question/concern...  If you're running both hot and cold pex lines in a common conduit/pipe for 30+ feet, I'd be concerned that what you get at the other end when you finally have your mixing valve is cold water that's no longer cold (picking up heat from the hot line) and hot water that's no longer hot (due to the cold water running next to it), in a confined space.  If possible, can you run them in separate pipes to keep the opposite temperature lines more separate from each other?

Answer (score 0):

If you tested that both lines fit into the PVC, then both lines fit in the PVC. If the two bends were made with a heat so that they are super long sweeps, then they won't give you much problem either. If you are using store-bought bends, then you don't have a chance. However, if the ends are short and the pex is installed into the straight pipe first, then the bend can be installed over the pex and glued onto the pipe last for a much easier job. I have created a few impossible pulls using what I call the 'install the pipe over the wire' technique.

Wire pulling lubricant always helps a lot and is often the difference between possible and impossible.

I find it interesting the you are putting the pex into another pipe.

Comment: The "install the pipe over the wire" technique also doesn't meet NEC because you can create impossible pulls: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/215039/why-can-i-not-assemble-conduit-around-cable-but-must-pull-it-after-assembly

Comment: Unless you have a super puller, I broke code a few times. I'm glad for my old age because code is getting overly concerned about everything. If lube was needed to install, then how to back out after dry? Adding another wire is almost always impossible and you risk rubbing a hole in the insulation of another wire. No matter how I prepare, helpers manage to twist the feed. Once wires are installed in a pipe with bends then that's the install and that's that. And that's common sense in an imperfect world which code has forgotten all about. Cut the pipe to modify the run if that is what is needed.

Comment: @FreeMan I don't think the NEC  applies to installing PEX water lines... :-)

Comment: No, it doesn't, @JACK, but Paul stated that, "I have created a few impossible pulls using what I call the 'install the pipe over the **wire**' technique." and that's what I was referring to. _Emphasis added._