# Securing Cables at Ends of Conduit Run

Tags: wiring, conduit, junction-box

As a follow-up to [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/108269/running-nm-b-in-pvc-sch-40-conduit-from-outdoor-breaker-panel/108278#108278%20this) question, if I have wet/damp location-rated cables going from an outdoor breaker box, up a ~5' SCH40 PVC conduit, and into a building attic, do I need to secure both ends of the cable to both the breaker box *and* and interior junction box or just the interior junction boxes?

At one end is the breaker box, but at the other end, the cables exit the large PVC conduit, run outside conduit (in the attic) a short distance, then enter a plastic junction box to be spliced to NM cable used for the interior wiring. The plastic junction boxes have cable clamps for the cable coming from the conduit.

Would this arrangement be admissible under the NEC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a cable goes from a breaker box (service panel) into a conduit, there's no need (and no decent method) to secure it.

Usually, wires exiting a panel go left, right or up, so it's not really much of an issue.  Gravity keeps them put.

Comment: Thanks Harper. Unfortunately, this question is no longer relevant since I can't really use the single large conduit as described in the linked question.