# Unfinished basement: OK to mount outlet box on wall?

Tags: electrical

If I hang this off a dedicated circuit (and the 2nd outlet is chained off the GFCI outlet), is it OK to have this box bolted right to the wall?

It is properly grounded and all. The plain (wrong color) outlet is daisied off the GFCI so they are all GFCI protected.

(This is in PA, if code varies by state)

**UPDATE**

It is clear that the right right way to do this is to have the leg down from the joists in flex or other conduit. However, there will be a washer and dryer in front of this box, so it won't be possible to reach the bare romex. And yes, the romex is stapled to the wall, it is not just hanging.

**SIDE QUESTION**

An interesting (to me) side question is: Would it be more appropriate if the GFCI was in the circuit breaker rather than in the outlet? I went the outlet-route because about half the cost (GFCI breakers being sooooo pricey.) I don't think there is a practical or code-perspective difference, but that is a thought.

[image]

Comment: If all the other necessary hoops are jumped through it should be fine.

Comment: The box is probably okay, but the cable I think needs to be protected.

Comment: Do not strip the outer jacket. [Can Romex (NM-B) cable be run through conduit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/31149/can-romex-nm-b-cable-be-run-through-conduit)

Answer (score 5):

The box is fine. Make sure you get the GFCI right - plain receptacle needs to be on the *LOAD* side of the GFCI. And technically should have a label indicating it is protected by the GFCI, but I would think it is a bit obvious. (Looks like you've got a white GFCI and an ivory/almond/beige plain receptacle. Technically OK, but *ugh*.)

As far as GFCI location, as long as it is properly wired, at the *first* receptacle is 100% fine. GFCI at the receptacle has a big advantage in convenience, particularly if all affected receptacles are in the same room. (Arguably if the circuit snakes all over the house, as many older circuits do, the circuit breaker is the more *obvious* place to look when there is a fault.) Plus they are cheaper than GFCI breakers, and with older panels (or panels stuffed with half-size breakers) GFCI breakers may not even be a practical option. The only real advantage of GFCI breakers is that they *guarantee* protection to the entire circuit. With GFCI receptacles, you may wire it correctly but when something goes wrong somebody else may, deliberately or not, rewire in a way that downstream receptacles lose protection.

The cable needs to be secured to the wall, and it also needs to be protected from damage where it is below (I think) 8'. Even something as simple as stacking boxes against the wall can damage an unprotected cable.

Comment: Like manaase... said, if it's below 8' from the floor it needs to be protected. Conduit is the typical choice, if appearance is an issue, wiremold products are more attractive.

Answer (score 3):

The box is fine but the Romex or NMB requires protection or conduit,

the least expensive way is to run the conduit to the ceiling then put a bushing on the end of the conduit and run the Romex (NMB) along the ceiling until you come back down to another box or the service panel.

it needs to be in conduit below 8’ or the ceiling level (of the ceilings are lower code allows them to be run exposed above 8’ no protection is required).

Comment: Yup, this is the relevant point here.