# How should cable (Romex) exit conduit to run bare along rafters in an unfinished detached garage?

Tags: electrical, conduit

I am going to be installing a subpanel in an unfinished detached garage, and would like to install receptacles in each corner of the building.

Since the garage is unfinished (cinderblock walls), I'm going to place all of the cable ( as Romex) in Schedule 40 PVC conduit for the vertical runs from the receptacles to the rafters. To run the Romex between the building corners, I plan to run it stapled across the rafters more than 7 feet up.

At the top of each vertical conduit run, do I have to install a terminal adapter the end of the conduit electrical box & splice it to a Romex that's clamped to the box? Or is there some kind of bushing or strain relief connector that I can use on the end of the conduit, so the same piece of Romex can be run from one corner to the next?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but see https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/31149/can-romex-nm-b-cable-be-run-through-conduit

Comment: What kind of "terminal adapter" are you thinking of? You may want to include a picture or at least a link to one.

Comment: With intact NM cable inside PVC conduit why do you need to do anything?  Just staple the cable near to where it exits the conduit.  The conduit protects the cable at lower levels, the plastic conduit end is not damaging to the plastic outer jacket of the cable, and the cable is appropriately fastened by staples to the ceiling.  Why add complexity?

Comment: @jay613, I would tend to accept that myself, but I just want to insure that it's acceptable to the electrical inspector. As I'm a DIYer, I didn't know if there were any restrictions via NEC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a female adapter like this
[image]

and attach it to your PVC and then screw this adapter into it after removing the lock nut (Stock photos from home Depot). You can also add a PVC 90 degree sweep in the direction of the run if neatness counts.

[image]

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Thanks... need more coffee

Comment: Thanks, @Jack. That sounds like it'll work. Hopefully the inspector will accept it.

Comment: Why don't you try one of these and one with a bare conduit end and see if the inspector accepts either or both.    I think this would be my preferred solution if the cable were exiting the conduit into, say, a suspended ceiling where I'm fishing it further and unable to fasten it to anything.  But if you're stapling at the transition, IMO either way is OK and either way equally likely to irk an inspector for no good reason.